# Program code is deleting the data which I want to keep

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that consolidate the values on another sheet, and based on these values, it´s has to go back on the first sheet and delete. But the macro is deleting what I want to keep.

[The sheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0toMHEjNi_fc09PRzZLa2xGODA).

```
The Macro:
Sub DeleteOthers()
    Dim r1 As Range, c As Range
    Dim t As String

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set r1 = .Range(.Cells(2, "H"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each c In r1
        If c.Text = "<<<Keep Row" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            t = c.Offset(0, -1)
            Rows(t).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Vityata gave the answer but I'd like to add that you shouldn't use `.Text`.  `.Text` is the string that is actually displayed on screen. So if your column get's to narrow, it becomes `"####"` and it will delete everything. Use `.Value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
If c.Text <> "<<<Keep Row" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vityata's answer gets right to the heart of the issue -- using `<>` instead of `=` is the chief issue here.

(Using @arcadeprecinct's recommendation of `c.Value` instead of `c.Text` is also a great idea.)

If you were to tackle this by hand in Excel, you probably wouldn't go line-by-line though -- right? You would use Excel's built-in filtering... and with VBA, you can get the same wonderful results in a hurry by using the `Range` object's built in `AutoFilter` method.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteOthersWithAutoFilter()
    Dim r1 As Range, c As Range

    'Grab the full data range, not just column H
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set r1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
    End With

    With r1

        'Apply the Autofilter method to column H in the range
        'identifying any cells NOT containing "<<<Keep Row"
        .AutoFilter Field:=8, _
                    Criteria1:="<><<<Keep Row"

        'Clear the remaining, visible rows while keeping the headers
        Set c = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        c.ClearContents

    End With

    'Clear the filter
    Sheets("Sheet2").AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

**Using `Range.AutoFilter` instead of looping through individual rows can be very fast, especially as your data sets get larger.**

You can learn more about the differences between the two strategies, looping through rows and `Range.AutoFilter`, here:

https://danwagner.co/how-to-delete-rows-with-range-autofilter/

Which includes a YouTube video benchmarking each in action.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but like this, it´s deleting on the sheet 2, if I change to sheet 1, where I wanna clear. I put before the Set c= and the c.clear, to look at the sheet1 to do the cleanning, but won´t work.